# Proving an inequality for the solution of a quadratic equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, roots, quadratics

I have a quadratic equation with unknown $x$ given as (all parameters are positive):
$$
a_{1}(x+m_{1}\frac{x^{2}}{2})-a_{2}(\tau+m_{2}\frac{\tau^{2}}{2})=0
$$
I want to show that the positive solution satisfies 
$$
x\geq\frac{a_{2}m_{2}}{a_{1}m_{1}}\tau
$$
assuming that 
$$
a_{1}(\tau+m_{1}\frac{\tau^{2}}{2})-a_{2}(\tau+m_{2}\frac{\tau^{2}}{2})\geq0
$$
and $a_{1}m_{1}\geq a_{2}m_{2}$.

**What I've tried:** 
If we write the solution to the quadratic equation we get:
$$
x=\frac{-a_{1}+\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+2a_{1}m_{1}(a_{2}\tau+a_{2}m_{2}\frac{\tau^{2}}{2})}}{a_{1}m_{1}}
$$
The term in the square root can be written as
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{1}^{2}+2a_{1}m_{1}(a_{2}\tau+a_{2}m_{2}\frac{\tau^{2}}{2}) & = & (a_{1}+a_{2}m_{2}\tau)^{2}-(a_{2}m_{2}\tau)^{2}-2a_{1}a_{2}m_{2}\tau\\
 &  & +2a_{1}m_{1}a_{2}\tau+a_{1}m_{1}a_{2}m_{2}\tau^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
so if we show that 
$$
-(a_{2}m_{2}\tau)^{2}-2a_{1}a_{2}m_{2}\tau+2a_{1}m_{1}a_{2}\tau+a_{1}m_{1}a_{2}m_{2}\tau^{2}\geq0
$$
we are done. But I haven't been able to reduce the above to the assumption.
What I get is instead 
\begin{eqnarray*}
-(a_{2}m_{2}\tau)^{2}-2a_{1}a_{2}m_{2}\tau+2a_{1}m_{1}a_{2}\tau+a_{1}m_{1}a_{2}m_{2}\tau^{2} & = & \tau^{2}a_{2}m_{2}(a_{1}m_{1}-a_{2}m_{2})+2\tau(a_{1}m_{1}a_{2}-a_{1}m_{2}a_{2})\\
 & \geq & \tau^{2}a_{2}m_{2}(a_{1}m_{1}-a_{2}m_{2})+2\tau a_{2}m_{2}(a_{2}-a_{1})
\end{eqnarray*}
which is not necessarily positive, but I believe that the inequality
must be still valid.

Comment: The given quadratic has $2$ roots of opposite signs (given the "*all parameters are positive*" assumption). Then you essentially state that both $x$ and $\tau$ are *the* positive root, which would in effect mean that they are one and the same. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @dxiv you are right; sorry. The second equality must have been an ineqality.

Comment: Then the statement is equivalent to $f(\frac{a_2 m_2}{a_1 m_1}\tau) \le 0$ for $f(x)$ being the function defined on the 2nd line, which is not obvious that it must be true given the premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that from solving your equation in $\tau$, $$\tau \geq \frac{2(a_2-a_1)}{a_1m_1-a_2m_2}$$ Then, we are looking to show that $$-a_1+\sqrt{a_1^2+2a_1m_1\left(a_2\tau+a_2m_2\frac{\tau^2}{2}\right)} \geq a_2m_2\tau$$ In the case that $a_2 > a_1$ (and $m_1 > m_2$), we note that $$a_2\tau+a_2m_2\frac{\tau^2}{2} \geq \frac{2a_2(a_2-a_1)}{a_1m_1-a_2m_2}+\frac{2a_2(a_1-a_2)^2m_2}{(a_1m_1-a_2m_2)^2} = \frac{2a_1a_2(a_2-a_1)(m_1-m_2)}{(a_1m_1-a_2m_2)^2}$$ Therefore, \begin{align*} a_1^2+2a_1m_1\left(a_2\tau+a_2m_2\frac{\tau^2}{2}\right) &\geq a_1^2+\frac{4a_1^2a_2(a_2-a_1)m_1(m_1-m_2)}{(a_1m_1-a_2m_2)^2} \\ &= \frac{a_1^2(a_1m_1-2a_2m_1+a_2m_2)^2}{(a_1m_1-a_2m_2)^2} \end{align*} We can see that as $a_1m_1 \geq a_2m_2$, $$a_1m_1-2a_2m_1+a_2m_2 \leq 2a_1m_1-2a_2m_1 = 2m_1(a_1-a_2) < 0$$ so $$\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2(a_1m_1-2a_2m_1+a_2m_2)^2}{(a_1m_1-a_2m_2)^2}} = -\frac{a_1(a_1m_1-2a_2m_1+a_2m_2)}{a_1m_1-a_2m_2}$$ so finally, \begin{align*} -a_1+\sqrt{a_1^2+2a_1m_1\left(a_2\tau+a_2m_2\frac{\tau^2}{2}\right)} &\geq -a_1-\frac{a_1(a_1m_1-2a_2m_1+a_2m_2)}{a_1m_1-a_2m_2} \\ &= \frac{2a_1(a_2-a_1)m_1}{a_1m_1-a_2m_2} \\ &= a_1m_1\tau\end{align*} As $a_1m_1 \geq a_2m_2$, we therefore have that $a_1m_1\tau \geq a_2m_2\tau$, so we are done with the first case.

Note that the inequality is not necessarily true in the case that $a_1 > a_2$. A counterexample, found by Mathematica, could be $a_1 = 8$, $a_2 = 1$, $m_1 = 1$, $m_2 = 5$, and $\tau = 2$. This gives us the positive solution $x = 1$, but $\frac{a_2m_2}{a_1m_1}\tau = \frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: I'm very sorry the second eqality is an ineqality otherwise we would just get $\tau=x$. I've edited the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's effectively the same solution, but with a couple more $\geq$'s instead of $=$'s. This is mainly because your solution in $x$ is an increasing function of $\tau$.

Comment: I've edited the solution to reflect your update.

Comment: But the positivity of $\tau$ doesn't imply $a_2>a_1$..

Comment: That's correct. If $a_1 \leq a_2$, then $\tau$ can be any positive number. I'll add an addendum to the solution to reflect that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the case I haven't been able to show i.e. $a_1>a_2$ but I think the inequality should still hold.

Comment: Actually, your inequality is false for the case $a_1 > a_2$. I've given a counterexample.